# File transfer via ssh to local machine

Tags: linux, ssh, file-transfer

Sometimes at work I need to ssh into a local server on the command line to do some handiwork. A couple of times I've needed to copy a file onto my local machine. I can do this with the cp command locally or on a server, but is there any easy way I can do this from the server to my local machine?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can [easily].  To do this between Linux boxes is trivial - you just use SCP (in much the same way as you use CP), but as you are not running an ssh daemon on your Windows desktop that won't work to well.

You should be able to pull files from the server onto your Windows box using something like WinSCP though.

Alternatively (and don't use windows so can't test it) you might be able to get away with running something like something like freeSSHd (which I found by googling, never used it) and then using SCP in much the same way as you would Linux -> Linux. See http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/itdojo/set-up-a-free-ssh-server-on-windows-7-with-freesshd/3506

Comment: Actually, I have a Linux box at work

Answer (score 1):

`scp` will copy files between 2 computers. `sshd` needs to be running on the remote system. if your local system is running under Windows - [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php) is a great Windows client.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to WinSCP, [FileZilla](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQFjAB&url=http://filezilla-project.org/download.php&ei=_WALUayODZHSrQfFyIHwAQ&usg=AFQjCNFsdqxb7lbxvpf2lEast3pyf0ykCQ&sig2=OFcx-QCU6fRtc4zaF7ayJA&bvm=bv.41867550,d.bmk) is also a great tool.

Comment: The OP is using linux.

Answer (score 1):

To copy files between Linux boxes using `scp` do (from the server):

```
scp local.txt user@remote.server:/foo/bar
```

to copy a local file to the remote directory `/foo/bar`.

To copy a file from the remote server to your local $HOME (from your local machine) do:

```
scp user@remote.server:/foo/bar/remote.txt ~/local_name.txt
```

If for some reason `scp` is not present in your machine (which is probably impossible if you have `ssh` installed) install the `openssh` package. For debian based distributions, do this:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh
```